# tracing memory leaks in Python (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing` application that leaks memory. However, the leak is not in the main process (according to [Dowser](http://www.aminus.org/blogs/index.php/2008/06/11/tracking-memory-leaks-with-dowser?blog=2) and `top`) but in the subprocesses. Is there any way I can use Dowser (or similar tool) on subprocesses to trace the leak? If not, how do it trace it?

UPDATE:I spent lots of time trying to use [heapy](http://www.smira.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/heapy.html) and [gnibbler's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641231/python-working-around-memory-leaks/1641280#1641280) but I couldn't locate the leak. I then stopped cherrypy in the main process and started another one (with [Dowser](http://www.aminus.org/blogs/index.php/2008/06/11/tracking-memory-leaks-with-dowser?blog=2)) in the subprocess. But after a few minutes CherryPy would stop listening to the port... :( So I'm still looking for a better idea.

Comment: try heapy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972653/using-heapy-to-track-down-memory-leaks-in-django-app

Comment: I spent last hour trying to figure out how to use it. Best docs I could find are [here](http://www.smira.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/heapy.html) but I still can't get the list of objects that make up most of the space. How do you use it?

Comment: How much is it leaking? Are you sure that it's actually leaking memory, and not miscounted shared memory between the main and sub processes?

Comment: Each process (I have 40 of them) leaked about 30MB per day, so it is quite noticeable. Also, system eventually starts using swap and becomes unresponsive. Do you have any idea how to debug subprocess memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have hunted down the memory leak (which was in external C library) by using [muppy](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/muppy.html) - great tool, I wish I found it sooner! Thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

I have found [memory_profiler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) very easy to use but I'm not sure how it interacts with multiprocessing since I've never used that module. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592072/1804546) for a short explanation and other answers in that thread for mention of other Python profilers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of posts that should prove quite helpful. Haven't had the time to digest all the information in them yet, but thought I'd post the links and allow you to have a look at them as well.

Marius Gedminas has two posts on hunting memleaks in a Python test suite. He's using the built-in `gc` and `inspect` modules and simply dumping object graphs onto disk as csv files, so the approach should work quite well even for `mp` applications.

I'll look into that my self later today when I get the time.

**UPDATE**

Marius released his test rig as an open source project called `objgraph` ([link](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/)). It tracks the `gc` object references but allows you to print out helpful information like how many instances of which type were added after a function call, and it allows you to see complete reference chains for objects.

The docs are pretty self explanatory and I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work with `mp` applications just as well.

However if your memory leak is coming from some underlying c library then this might not help you. At least it should give you an idea where the leak is. If it turns out not to be in your python code then you might have to refactor your code so that you can run the relevant c-libraries in the main process and use something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect the leak.

---

The original post
http://mg.pov.lt/blog/hunting-python-memleaks.html

The one where he goes more into the tools he's using
http://mg.pov.lt/blog/python-object-graphs.html

The post that got me started
http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks