# memory leak using scapy sessions

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scapy, psutil, guppy

Currently experiencing high memory usage by scapy 2.4.0 on python 2.7 running on centos 7.4

originally I thought it was due to https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5149/rdpcap-and-wrpcap-file-descriptor-leak but this was was fixed some time ago.

```
import scapy
from guppy import hpy
import psutil
hp = hpy()


class SessionBuilder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_sessions(pcap):
        # this heap always reports 50mb usage
        hp.heap()
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        # I expect this memory to be around 50mb... but that's not always true
        print process.memory_info()
        opened_pcap = rdpcap("pcap_location")
        sessions = opened_pcap.session()
        # this heap always reports 50mb usage
        hp.heap()
        # I expect this memory to be larger which is it
        print process.memory_info()
        return sessions
```

inside aonther python file

```
import SessionBuilder
class session_worker
    def __init__(self):
        self.sb = SessionBuilder()

    def work(self):
        for pcap in pcaps:
            sessions = self.sb.get_sessions(pcap)


        # I then go about doing some things with these sessions
```

apologies for some mistakes in the code but it's on an offline system so just added a rough chunk of what I'm doing.

every time I go around the loop there is a chance that the memory from the previous loop stays and this just compounds until I have no memory left
(not featured in the code above but there is some logic in place that will ignore any pcap that is larger than 1/4 of available memory on the box to ensure that scapy can open it an extract the sessions)

according to [Using heapy to track down memory leaks in Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972653/using-heapy-to-track-down-memory-leaks-in-django-app) the heap amount of representative of the memory that python is using and not any underlying c code. I'm assuming scapy uses c underneath?

Comment: Someone left a comment but either they deleted it or I can't see it. Anyways I solved this by implementing my own version of a lower level function inside the scapy source code. By doing this I was able to read the amount of pcaps I wanted and build sessions out of them before rinsing and repeating but leaving the pcap reader open. Hope this helps anyone that comes into this issue later on